# Product id missing attribute id

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, subquery, having-clause

I have a table with prodID , attrID
Each prodID have 1-5 atrrID's
I want to list the prodIDs which don't have a specific atrrID, eg "c"

```
+-----------+---------+
| prodID    | attrID  | 
+-----------+---------+
| 1         | a       | 
| 1         | b       |
| 1         | c       | 
| 2         | a       | 
| 2         | b       | 
| 2         | d       |
| 3         | b       | 
| 3         | c       | 
| 3         | d       |
| 4         | a       | 
| 4         | b       | 
| 4         | d       | 
| 4         | e       | 
| 5         | a       | 
| 5         | b       | 
| 6         | a       | 
| 6         | d       |   
+-----------+---------+
```

The result should be

```
+-----------+
| prodID    |
+-----------+
| 2         |
| 4         | 
| 5         |
| 6         |
+-----------+
```

Table name is
rp_prod_attr_list

Comment: You need to show the query as well. We can't fix what we can't see. Is this a case of `WHERE attrID NOT IN (...)`?

Comment: Hi!
 i don't have any query , I am asking for a query suggestion!

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select prodid
from mytable 
group by prodid
having max(attrid = 'c') = 0
```

In MySQL, a condition evaluated in numeric context returns `1` if fullfilled, else `0`. So `max(attr_id = 'c') = 0` phrases as: there is no row in the group that satisfies the condition.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
select distinct prodid
from prod p
where not exists (select null
                  from prod p_
                  where p_.prodid = p.prodid
                   and attrID = 'c')
```